Python call to DLL via CDLL Results in "STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN" Exception
I'm trying to make a call to an  (https://www.autelrobotics.com/doc/609/) via a DLL in Python and the app crashes before the call returns.  The Windows error logs show it to be a "STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN" exception, but I would think would mean that one of the variables being passed isn't sized correctly.
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import faulthandler

faulthandler.enable()

sdk_path = 'dependencies/autel/AutelIrTempParserSDK.dll'
ir_temp_parse = ctypes.CDLL(sdk_path)

# Define the data structures
class Autel_IR_INFO_S(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('tag', ctypes.c_uint16),
        ('len', ctypes.c_uint16),
        ('show_value', ctypes.c_char * 512),
        ('str_value', ctypes.c_char * 512),
        ('num_value', ctypes.c_int)
    ]

class QPointF(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ctypes.c_int),
        ('y', ctypes.c_int)
    ]

class TempStatInfo(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('max', ctypes.c_float),
        ('min', ctypes.c_float),
        ('avg', ctypes.c_float),
        ('maxPoint', QPointF),
        ('minPoint', QPointF)
    ]

# Define the function prototypes
ir_temp_parse.GetIrPhotoTempInfo.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_char_p,  # filepath
    ctypes.c_int,     # w
    ctypes.c_int,     # h
    ctypes.POINTER(TempStatInfo),  # tempStatInfo
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p),  # result (map<string, Autel_IR_INFO_S>)
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))  # tempArray (2D array)
]
ir_temp_parse.GetIrPhotoTempInfo.restype = ctypes.c_int

ir_temp_parse.GetRawTempData.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_char_p,  # filepath
    ctypes.c_int,     # w
    ctypes.c_int,     # h
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16)  # rawTempData
]
ir_temp_parse.GetRawTempData.restype = ctypes.c_int

filepath = b'images/autel/IRX_0001_south.jpg'

w, h = 640, 512

tempStatInfo = TempStatInfo()
result = ctypes.cast(ctypes.c_void_p(), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
tempArray = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) * h)()
for i in range(h):
    tempArray[i] = (ctypes.c_float * w)()
     
ret = ir_temp_parse.GetIrPhotoTempInfo(filepath, w, h, ctypes.byref(tempStatInfo), result, tempArray)
if ret == 0:
        print("GetIrPhotoTempInfo succeeded!")
        # Access the results as needed
else:
    print("GetIrPhotoTempInfo failed!")

#ret = _GetRawTempData(filepath, 640, 512, rawTempData)


Screenshots from SDK




It’s “C”types. C++ maps, vectors, strings aren’t supported.

Does this answer your question? How to use C++ classes with ctypes?

STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN doesn't mean what you think it does, see: STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN doesn’t mean that there was a stack buffer overrun

Unfortunately I don’t have a way to change the provided DLL. The best solution I could come up with is to build a new DLL wrapper that returned C Types.
